# build report settings from sql that override defaults

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a reporting system that allows users to customize reports and each user can create a custom report on top of a data grid.

```
 ID GRIDID               USER_ID REPORTNAME  REPORTPAYLOAD CREATED            
--- -------------------- ------- ----------- ------------- ------------------ 
  4 CompleteReportView1  User1   Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
  6 CompleteReportView1  User1   All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48  
 10 CompleteReportView1          Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
 12 CompleteReportView1          All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48  
 16 CompleteReportView1          Default     (CLOB)        4/18/2011 9:53:38  
 18 CompleteReportView1  User2   Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
 20 CompleteReportView1  User2   All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48  
 33 CompleteReportView1  User3   Default     (CLOB)        4/18/2011 9:53:38
```

I want the report list for a specific user to include all the reports they have setup, as well as the ones for User_Id's of null.  If a user has name a report the same as a user_id=null report, then only theirs is returned.

Here is the datasets I would like returned:
User_Id = User1

```
 ID GRIDID               USER_ID REPORTNAME  REPORTPAYLOAD CREATED            
--- -------------------- ------- ----------- ------------- ------------------ 
  4 CompleteReportView1  User1   Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
  6 CompleteReportView1  User1   All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48  
 16 CompleteReportView1          Default     (CLOB)        4/18/2011 9:53:38
```

User_Id = User2

```
 ID GRIDID               USER_ID REPORTNAME  REPORTPAYLOAD CREATED            
--- -------------------- ------- ----------- ------------- ------------------ 
 16 CompleteReportView1          Default     (CLOB)        4/18/2011 9:53:38  
 18 CompleteReportView1  User2   Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
 20 CompleteReportView1  User2   All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48
```

User_Id = User3

```
 ID GRIDID               USER_ID REPORTNAME  REPORTPAYLOAD CREATED            
--- -------------------- ------- ----------- ------------- ------------------ 
 10 CompleteReportView1          Completed   (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:05  
 12 CompleteReportView1          All         (CLOB)        4/18/2011 8:40:48  
 33 CompleteReportView1  User3   Default     (CLOB)        4/18/2011 9:53:38
```

Can someone help with the sql I need? I am open to modifying the table structure if that makes the best sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to do this, and to some extent it depends on how database-agnostic you want to be.  Something like this should work on most dbs:

```
select *
from   T
where  USER_ID = :user
union
select *
from   T
where  USER_ID is null
and    REPORTNAME not in (
    select REPORTNAME
    from   T
    where  USER_ID = :user
)
```

assuming `T` is the name of the table above and `:user` is User1, User2, etc...

Whether this is the best way to build the table or not is a different question.  If you really just want default reports, you might want a different approach.  Note too that this may not perform well if the table gets large.

Comment: The second part of the question, that is not handled by that is, there are records for reportname = 'Default' for User3 and User null and I only want the User3's report if it exists.

Comment: I updated the sql and I think it should take that into account now.